# How can I snap the center of the bottom part of a box to the center of a plane?

Tags: modeling, objects

How can I snap the center of the bottom part of a box to the center of a plane?

I have read the other posts related to this, but they are too confusing.

Answer (score 5):

1. In *edit mode* select bottom face of cube, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selected*
2. *Object mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *Origin to 3D cursor*
3. Select the plane
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selected*
5. Select the cube
6. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *Selected  to Cursor, Offset*

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it as Timaroberts and mooboots understand it, check if the plane and the box have their origins in the center of their mass. If they do, use Transform > Align Objects from the Object menu in the Object Mode. Otherwise select Origin to the center of mass before you align. If the box and plane are away from each other move the box along Z axis with SnapTo > Nearest face enabled.

OR, if you want to do it as shown below:

Select the bottom face of the box and poke it. Align box with the plane as I wrote above if necessary. Select the plane and click Cursor to Selected. Select the central vertex of the box' poked bottom face and click Selection to 3D Cursor to get the result shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *Snap to* option (*Face* mode) to snap the cube to the face:

[image]

Then select the cube, shift select the plane to make it the active object and *Object > Transform > Align Objects*:

[image]

In the *Operator* box, choose *Relative to > Active* and press X and Y:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Add a large plane where you want the cube's face to end up.
- Move the cube so the face in question is really close to the new plane (doesn't have to touch the plane).
- From the controls near the top of the screen, select Snap To Face Nearest (from the little dropdown). Make sure the nearby magnet icon is not selected (i.e. don't snap during transform).
- Left-click to select the cube, then shift-left-click to also select the plane.
- From the Object menu select Transform and then Align Objects.
- From the Align Objects floating control window, make sure that the Z line is selected, i.e. becomes blue (and the X and Y lines are not selected), select Negative Sides as the Align Mode, and select Active as Relative To.
- Enjoy.